# 2 gallon tank pressurized to 100 psi connected with a tube to a tractor tire with only 30 psi

Tags: pressure, air, volume

2 gallon tank pressurized to 100 psi connected with a tube to  a large tractor tire with only 30 psi.

And the air does not move from tank to tire.

Why? Can anyone link a YouTube video to explain the phenomenon

Thx

I found this out when I purchased a small 2 gallon tank to fill up Tire. The tank is pressurized to 100 psi. And a tire chuck to tractor tire and no air movement happening.

I am told to get 10 gallon tank to fill up tire to 40 or 60psi

Which physics law is this and is there a YouTube link that can explain this like i am 5 years old
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, where there is a pressure difference, air should flow. Now, some possibilites in figuring out *why air is not flowing from gallon tank to tractor tire*.

Possibilites:

*i)Faulty instrument - check whether gallon tank that you are using is faulty or not.*

*ii)Blockages in between the path- check for any possible blockages in the path between the two components(gallon tank and tire).*

*iii)Point of connection- Check properly the point of connection of pipe  at two points, first at gallon tank and the other at tire.*

Also consider 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9IDd.jpg) image: In that image, check whether green knob is turned on or not.

Comment: this is the answer. pushing the tire chuck harder the air flows again. it will until 100 PSi I am sure.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a path, air will move from high pressure to low pressure.  So if air is not moving at all (the tank maintains full pressure), then some aspect of the connection is blocking the movement.

That said, this task will be difficult depending on what you mean by a "large" tractor tire.  A 540/65R34 (big, but not the largest) holds over 250 gallons.  Even 100 psi is going to struggle to increase that by much.

What's the final pressure if that tractor tire started at 30psi and a 10 gallon tank started at 100psi?

$$n = kPV$$
$$n_{tank} = (100) (10)\text{gal psi}, n_{tire} = (30)(250)\text{gal psi}$$
$$n_{total} = 8500 \text{gal psi}$$
$$P_{final} = \frac{n}{V} = \frac{8500 \text{gal psi}}{260\text{gal}} = 32.7\text{psi}$$

Comment: I leave out some details. The tire is actually only 275/65/16 not that big. but the tank is only 2 Gallon. the tire was flat at start. it fills up to 29PSI then it stop. The compressor was running  until it stop when the tank is at 100PSI (approx the needle is hard to read) .. I can't fill up any more. I thought it is some kind of physics limitation. but it could be a faulty tools then? some also suggest I didn't push the tire chuck hard enough

Comment: Nothing physics related seems likely.  High pressure flows to low pressure as long as there is a path.

Comment: yup it's user error. I didn't push the tire chuck hard enough.It's fine all the way tp 50 PSI so it's a dumb user.